# Multi threaded and event driven

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous-programming

I got this problem in an interview and want to confirm multi threading adds no value here.

Case:

- You are writing an agent to buy stocks.
- The agent is initialized with a set of stocks to buy when they hit a certain price.
- A separate (out of scope) service monitors the market and invokes a callback on your agent when a pice changes (agent implements some interface that provides the callback method)
- The callback can be invoked for stocks you don't care about,  and when it's invoked for a stock you do care about, you need to check the price is the price you want to buy at.
- When you determine you should buy, you invoke some external out of scope service.
- The agent will be run asynchronously from some engine that creates it.
- When all the stocks (at the desired price) have been bought, the agent shuts down.
- The engine that inits the agent is out of scope.

I don't see the benefit of having the agent asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

I understand from your statement that in the case, the agent is run asynchronously in a separate thread.

Imagine what would happen if the agent would execute synchronously:

- the monitoring service would call the agent and wait until the agent is finished.
- in the meantime it does no longer monitor anything
- perhaps even it will miss a good opportunity because the price went down while the service was waiting for the agent and went up again later
- perhaps the monitoring service serves several agents running for different customers, several event watching for the same stocks.  These other agents would then be on hold, missing opportunities (and the clients claim for equal treatment).

The asynchronous agent lets the monitoring service continue its monitoring without being stuck.  Even if the first buy is not finished, the monitoring service could already invoke a new purchase benefiting from the low price (in case several agents run concurrently) before it goes up (or if there's a single agent, at least it will not miss the hitting of a certain price ).

Note also that in case of multiple agents, each agent could also wait for connection with a transactional system that registers the buying. A synchronous connection would further slow down your monitoring system.  With asynchronous design, the waiting agents do not propagate the delays.  So in the end, you would certainly also observe a higher throughput.

So yes, asynchronous multithreading is a real benefit here.  It's the key to reactivity of a complex system, whether it's for [user interfaces](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/) or [trading systems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7919531/3723423).